# Delete duplicate records in MySQL table without unique ID with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are many solutions to delete duplicate records in a table in MySQL(8+).
But just as a curiosity, is there any solution to do it just with one query on a table without a unique ID column?

For example:

```
    CREATE TABLE employee
( 
  employee_name varchar(20),
  age int
);
insert into employee
                (employee_name,age)
                values
                ('Thiago',28),
                ('Thiago',28),
                ('Thiago',28),
                ('Sara',20),
                ('Mike',27);
```

Comment: This answer means there is no solution to delete without adding unique IDs?

Comment: Thanks @nnichols. Can you provide more details about your last suggestion?

Comment: Ensuring that some combination of columns uniquely identifies each row is a fairly basic early step in correctly modelling your data. You don't really have data at this point, just a random assortment of individual details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this to get the counts of duplicates:

```
SELECT employee_name, age, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM employee
GROUP BY employee_name, age
HAVING num > 1;
```

Which for your example would return:

| employee_name | age | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thiago | 28 | 3 |

You then loop over the result set (just one in this case) running a DELETE for each dupe returned:

```
/* pseudocode */
foreach (rows as row) {
    DELETE FROM employee
    WHERE employee_name = row.employee_name
    AND age = row.age
    LIMIT row.num - 1
}
```

You could do this in a stored procedure or whichever language you choose.

Personally, I would go for the following approach in SQL:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_employees AS
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM employee;

TRUNCATE TABLE employee;
ALTER TABLE employee ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, age)
SELECT * FROM tmp_employees;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_employees;
```

You could also add a new primary key to the existing table and then apply any of the many dupe delete approaches:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

This will add and populate a new AI PK.